# Cordova: Alerts not shown on desktop environment (They work fine on simulator and real device)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a pet project using Cordova. At the moment, target platform is only IOS.During the development, I was using alerts land marks to ensure what I intended was actually happening.(Personally, I found, alerts are easier to work with in simple cases where as logs are much handy in complex scenarios). At some point in the code, I have a button and a function that gets executed when that button is clicked.

Related cordova plugin is included, as you can see below the terminal output:

```
cordova plugins
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

I have tied up alert function into window object for convenience:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  console.log("deviceready");
  if (navigator.notification) { 
      window.alert = function (message) {
          navigator.notification.alert(
              message,    // message
              null,       // callback
              "My Awesome App", // title
              'OK'        // buttonName
          );
      };
      startApp();  // This is the kick off point for my app
  }
}, false);
```

**UPDATE 3** : I suspect that above window.alert assignment is bugging things up. If I comment out this assignment, regular alerts works as expected (but they look ugly). **Does anyone see anything suspicious with this usage?**

In the startApp function, I have the following line to bind the click event to the button:

```
$('#startActionButton').on('click', {name: 'this is really not need'}, someView.startAction);
```

My startAction function lives in a View class and defined as:

```
this.startAction = function(event){
    window.alert('Starting Action');
    console.log('Starting Action');
}
```

This code works perfectly fine on IOS simulator and on a real IOS device. However, it is time consuming to deploy the code each and everytime to either platforms. So, I prefer to develop on responsive desktop environment for the most part, and then do a detailed testing in either simulator or real device at the end of each development cycle.

So, when I ran the application in desktop environment with:

```
cordova serve
```

I **do** see that **Starting Action** in the console log. However, I do not get the alert.!

Here are my questions.

1. Does anyone have any idea why it would be?
2. I debugged the code, and put a break point in the startAction function, on the line of alert function. There, in debugger window, I typed the following and got the responses as below:

[image: window.alert is defined and undefined? WTH??]

Any idea how come is window.alert undefined although I can confirm that it exists and it has the correct source code?

This is not a road blocker problem for me, as I can live with console.logs but I am just curious, why alerts are failing to work on desktop environment. Is there any known bug in Cordova code? Am I missing anything? Just curious.

Any insight would be highly appreciated.

PS: I would like to add before asked that I also removed and re-installed the notifications plugin. But it did not help the case.

PS2: Version of cordova I am using is:

```
cordova -version
8.0.0
```

**UPDATE 1**
I forgot to add, I am also using ratchet.css (not js) for formatting, although I believe it has nothing to do with it.

**UPDATE 2**
Asked by @Gandhi, I have cordova.js included in my index.html

**UPDATE 4**
I renamed the custom alert as follows:

```
  window.myalert = function (message) {
      navigator.notification.alert(
          message,    // message
          null,       // callback
          "My Awesome App", // title
          'OK'        // buttonName
      );
  };
```

Now I can confirm that regular JS alerts work whereas this custom myalert still does not.

Comment: Did you try to use simple `alert("This is alert!");`

Comment: Thank you. And yes, I tried that too. But it does not work either.

Comment: That's wierd. For me [works](https://imgur.com/a/TEG0Y) fine..

Comment: Totally agree, weird indeed. It is supposed to work.

Comment: Try to use alert outside deviceready function

Comment: @Alp window.alert will return undefined in console as it don't have any return value. But navigator.notification.alert should work fine in desktop. Are you using browser platform? Cordova.js file added in your HTML?

Comment: @Gandhi yes, cordova.js is inluded in my index.html. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @proofzy Thank you for your suggestion. I narrowed down the problem to window.alert assignment. See my update 3 above please.

Comment: @Alp Why don't you just use browser platform which should serve your purpose of desktop testing?

Comment: @Gandhi there is no way, desktop will be a deployment target for this platform. This app is strictly IOS atm. May be Android in the far future but never a desktop. Is this a best practice to add an unnecessary platform to the project just for testing purposes? (I am truly not trying to be a smarty pants here, this is just a sincere question for more experienced Cordova developers).

Comment: @Alp I complete understand your question.Actually i dont feel its unnecessary. Infact the actual intent of browser platform is to test the app easily. Add browser platform, test and remove the platform once you are done. Its not so complex. Check this article - https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform/ which gives more clarity

Comment: @Gandhi Thank you for your suggestion. I added osx platform (which is what I am using for IOS dev). Unfortunately, there is no change in custom alert behavior :( I still do NOT see alerts via window.myalert('Blah');

Comment: @Alp You gotta add 'browser' platform if you gotta test this in broswer

Comment: @Gandhi Awesome! That did the trick.! Thank you very much. If you give these information as an answer, for future reference for this thread, I will gladly accept it. Thank you again for your help :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary intent of the OP is to develop and test the app in desktop environment so that the turn around time is quick. Once the application is tested in desktop environment, it can be ported to iOS simulator for further testing.

The 'browser' platform in cordova is tailor made for this requirement which helps in testing the app using browser like Chrome. You can check out the [following link](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform/) for more info on browser platform. Hope it helps.